# Shell function to return nested JSON property

Tags: json, shell, parsing

I'm looking to write a shell function to return single nested property value from an input JSON file.

The format of the JSON file `cookie.json` is:

```
"personalizationID": {
            "expires": null,
            "path": "/api",
            "secure": false,
            "value": "1458234194659-16"
        },
        "taxCode": {
            "expires": null,
            "path": "/api",
            "secure": false,
            "value": "aEFPyynhwJyzAHyfjXUlrGhblTtxWduqtCDMLxiD"
        }
```

So I was trying:

```
cat cookie.json | grep taxCode | cut -f 7
```

But it is returning just `"taxCode": {`. I need a function that, given three parameters, filenames `cookie.json`, outerProperty `taxCode` and nestedProperty `value`, returns me the value of the innerProperty `aEFPyynhwJyzAHyfjXUlrGhblTtxWduqtCDMLxiD`. I don't want to use any other library for just one-nested value extraction. How can I do this?

Comment: I've come up with a hard coded command:  
`cat cookie.json | grep -A5 taxCode | grep -e "value"`  
which return me: `"value": "aEFPyynhwJyzAHyfjXUlrGhblTtxWduqtCDMLxiD"`
Now I need to parse and extract the rhs bit.

Comment: I came up with the following command:
`taxCode=$(cat cookie.json | grep -A5 taxCode | grep -e "value" | cut -f 2 -d : | sed -e 's/\"//g')
  taxCode="${taxCode#"${taxCode%%[![:space:]]*}"}"`  

It is sensitive but it works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should have a look at jq

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). If `cookies.json` contains correct sample data then the following 
command

```
$ jq -M -r .taxCode.value cookies.json
```

produces

```
aEFPyynhwJyzAHyfjXUlrGhblTtxWduqtCDMLxiD
```